# Javascript: Find all elements on page and add the same CSS

Tags: javascript

Currently learning JavaScript and trying to create an expanding Menu.

I'm trying to find all elements of the same class and setting a CSS value on click for all elements in the NodeList. The error I see in console is:

```
Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

I know it's something to do with the for loop not setting the variable correctly; just not too sure what it is.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/dXv68/

**HTML**

```
<div class="master">

<a href="#" id="btn-nav">
    <span></span>
    <span>Menu</span>
    <span></span>
</a>

<nav id="main-nav">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background">
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>

  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>

  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
  <div class="slice"></div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>

</div><!-- end master -->
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans);


body {
    background: #2980b9;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
}


#btn-nav {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
        z-index:1;
}

#btn-nav span:nth-child(2) {
    top:10px;
}

#btn-nav span:nth-child(3) {
    top:20px;
}

#btn-nav span {
    height: 4px;
    width: 30px;
    background: white;
    content: "";
    text-indent: -999em;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    zoom: 1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition: top .3s cubic-bezier(0.165,.84,.44,1);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}


#btn-nav:hover > span {
    top:10px;
        -webkit-animation: rotateAni .5s 1s forwards; 
}

#btn-nav:hover > span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateAni .5s .5s forwards, expandAni .3s .8s forwards;
}

#btn-nav:hover > span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateAni .5s .5s forwards, expandAni-2 .3s .8s forwards;
}

#btn-nav:hover > span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateAni .5s .5s forwards, expandAni-3 .3s .8s forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes rotateAni {
  0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandAni {
  0% {left:0;}
  100% {left:-10px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandAni-2 {
  0% {left:0;}
  100% {left:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes expandAni-3 {
  0% {left:0;}
  100% {left:10px;}
}


#main-nav {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}

#main-nav .wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.slice {
  width:25%;
  height:30%;
  float:left;
  background:black;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.background {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

**JS**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var menuBtn = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
    var slice = document.querySelectorAll('.slice');

    for(var i = 0; i <= slice.length; i++) {
        var boxes = slice[i];
    }

    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        boxes.style.opacity = 1;
    }, false);

}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the for loop inside the event, as all it's doing currently is setting the LAST slice's opacity.

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
var slice = document.querySelectorAll('.slice');

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        slice[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to only run the loop once onLoad, instead of every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @user1381806 You need to iterate through each element in the click so that you can set each element's opacity to 1. By setting `var boxes = slice[i]` inside the loop within the onload, you're resetting `boxes` to equal only the last slice. Either way, you're going to have to iterate through all of the elements within the event.

Comment: Just a little clarification which I think may have caused the confusion: when you have `var boxes = slice[i];` inside the loop, it doesn't set `boxes` to reference all of the slices. Only the last one that was called to it.

Comment: Still get the same error 
 Cannot read property 'style' of undefined but it works.

Comment: Make sure you change that `i <= slice.length` to `i < slice.length` so that it wont error out.

Comment: Yes, that works thanks. Does it error out because 'i' isn't set yet?

Comment: No, it errors out because the for loop will iterate from 0 TO the length in a 0-based index. Say for example, there are 3 elements in slide. They are defined in indexes 0, 1, 2. The for loop with `i <= slice.length` will set `i` to equal 0, 1, 2, and 3. But 3 doesn't *exist* so it's `undefined`, so it will say "Welp. style of `undefined` doesn't exist."

Answer (score 1):

i liked your code, here follows a gift for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dXv68/3/

here is the secret:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var menuBtn = document.getElementById('btn-nav');
    var slice = document.querySelectorAll('.slice');

    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        for(var key in slice) {
            slice[key].style.opacity = 1;
        }
    }, false);

}());
```

Comment: Thanks for liking it :) - reading up about the in operator now

Comment: @user1381806 - since you're learning JS, one thing to note is that `for in` loops are much slower than traditional loops. They're great for iterating over objects, but frowned upon for arrays.

Comment: What @JackPattishallJr. said is true, i used because is an object but for array you should use the normal loop.

Comment: @Sakai - That's a great point, actually! NodeList are `array-like` objects.